# Signal R store value into global variable

Tags: post, global-variables, signalr, signalr-hub

Hi im currently trying to get a value from my view and store it in a global variable declared in my hub.
so that i can use it throughout my hub

however i have no idea how to sen the value from my view to the hub and store it in a variable in my hub
using Signal R

Example:

View: value=1
hub: int id

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I quite follow your question, but you can simply from your View call a method on a SignalR client and pass the value as a parameter. Server side, from within the handling method for the call, you could set the global variable in your hub?

Louis